# How to Plot a Bar Graph in Pandas for frequency Count?

Tags: pandas

I have a table -

```
   ProductCD    Frequency
0     C           62192
1     R           37548
2     H           32908
3     S           11585
```

How do I plot a bar graph to show Frequency of ProductCD ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
df.set_index('ProductCD')['Frequency'].plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.plot.bar(x = 'ProductCD', y = 'Frequency', rot = 0)
```